# Estimation of shape area given random points inside it

Tags: statistics

I have a shape $S$ of area $A$, but I do not know what $A$ is. However, I do have the coordinates of $N$ points (the coords are $(x_i,y_i)$ for $i\in[1,N]$) that follow a sampling distribution $D$. The probability density of $D$ is $0$ on points not enclosed by $S$ and uniform for points enclosed by $S$.

What is the estimation of $A$?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks! Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area of any shape can be written: $A=\sigma^2\gamma(S)$ where $\gamma$ is a scale factor and $\sigma$ is the 2D radius of gyration. $$\hat A=s^2\gamma(S)$$

Where $s$ is the sample standard deviation.

If we don't know what kind of shape $S$ we have, a simple choice is to treat the underlying area as ellipsoid. We calculate the covariance matrix
$$\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
\operatorname{var}(X) & \operatorname{cov}(X,Y)\\
\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) & \operatorname{var}(Y)\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
The eigenvectors of this matrix are in the direction of the semi-axes of the ellipse we're after and the eigenvalues are the variances in the respective semi-axes. We only need to look at the latter, and considering we desire (the square root of) their product, we simply require the determinant of the covariance matrix because this equals the product of the eigenvalues. $$A=\pi ab$$
If the points come from the ellipse defined by $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, the variance of $X$ is $\operatorname{var}(X)=\frac{a^2}{4}$, and variance of $Y$ is $\operatorname{var}(Y)=\frac{b^2}{4}$. That is to say that the length of the semi-axis is two standard deviations (i.e. $2\times\frac{a}{2}$).
$$\begin{align}\hat A &= \pi(2\sigma_1)(2\sigma_2)\\ &=4\pi\sqrt{\lambda_1}\sqrt{\lambda_2}\\&=4\pi\sqrt{\operatorname{det}(\Sigma)}\end{align}$$ Our result is:

$$\begin{align}\hat A &= 4\pi\sqrt{\operatorname{var}(X)\operatorname{var}(Y)-\left(\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)\right)^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! What exactly do you mean by "scale factor"?

Comment: $\gamma$ is a constant over shapes that are [similar](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Similar.html) to each other

Comment: So I must know something about $S$ first?

Comment: Yes. Do you know anything about $S$?

Comment: Nah but I thought it shouldn't be relevant... Can't you deduce $\gamma$ from the points themselves? I mean intuitively they should be related.

Comment: If you don't know the shape, then the estimate becomes more complicated. You could assume the shape to be an ellipse of area $\pi a b$? Otherwise if you assume the shape is a convex polygon, I think you would have to use something like the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula)...

Comment: Can you just give me the formula for $\gamma$?

Comment: What kind of problem are you solving? $\gamma$ is depends on the shape, e.g. area of a triangle is different to the area of an ovoid.

Comment: How about just like you proposed, we suppose it is an ellipse.

Comment: See the edited answer

Comment: Thank you! I'll move the comments to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147104/discussion-between-shiran-yuan-and-localth).